# Difference between 2-way of adding AppSetting

Tags: xml, app-config, appsettings

What is different between Case A and Case B?
Please help me to figure it out.

```
<appSettings>
 <add key="AAA" value="0"></add>  //CASE A
 <add key="BBB" value="1"/>       //CASE B
</appSettings>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each tag opened has to be closed. XML is pedantic about this. However, if a tag is empty (no content), a single tag can serve as both the opening and closing tag if it ends with `/>` rather than with `>`. Note that, for example, the image tag has no content (just an attribute) and is closed by ending the tag with `/>`.

c.f. http://xmlsoft.org/XMLinfo.html